# Cannot fill input text in react

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

I'm new to react and learn it through [a tutorial](https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_web3.0) about ethereum. Here is how the form with multiple fields is created

```
const Input = ({ placeholder, name, type, value, handleChange }) => (
    <input
      placeholder={placeholder}
      type={type}
      step="0.0001"
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, name)}
      className="noTailwind"
    />
  );

<Input placeholder="address to" name="addressTo" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
<Input placeholder="Amount (ETH)" name="amount" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
<Input placeholder="Keyword (Gif)" name="keyword" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
<Input placeholder="Enter message" name="message" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
```

Then `handleChange` is called in `TransactionContext.jsx`:

```
   const [formData, setformData] = useState({ addressTo: "", amount: "", keyword: "", message: "" });

   const handleChange = (e, name) => {
       console.log('handling change:', name, e.target.value);
    setformData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: e.target.value }));
  };
```

When I type in the form I see the first letter (keypress) appears in the console, but nothing is shown in the form and other key pressess are not registered.
I seem in the console messages like `handling change: amount g` and that's all

I'm wondering what is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing a value to the `Input`s:

```
<Input placeholder="address to" name="addressTo" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
```

So in

```
const Input = ({ placeholder, name, type, value, handleChange }) => (
```

the `value` prop is `undefined`.

Pass down the form data, and then access the `[name]` property on it.

Your `handleChange` function is also broken, because it tries to access the React event handler *after* the asynchronous state setter function gets called - React [synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html) should only be directly accessed synchronously.

Live demo:

```js
const Input = ({ placeholder, name, type, formData, setformData }) => {
    return <input
        placeholder={placeholder}
        type={type}
        step="0.0001"
        value={formData[name]}
        onChange={(e) => { setformData({ ...formData, [name]: e.currentTarget.value }) }}
        className="noTailwind"
    />
};

const App = () => {
    const [formData, setformData] = React.useState({ addressTo: "", amount: "", keyword: "", message: "" });
    return <Input placeholder="address to" name="addressTo" type="text" {...{ formData, setformData }} />
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: That took me way too long to figure out. You can't use the callback form of the state setter here because then it'll be called asynchronously, after the change event has completed (and React has released the event to be re-used elsewhere)

Comment: If you use the same code as mine, it should work just fine, as it does in the snippet - press "Run code snippet" to see it working in action. If it's not working, there must be some important difference not shown in the question.

Comment: On line 25 of TransactionContext.jsx, you definitely need to refactor `handleChange` to not be callback-based (as my answer says), otherwise you'll be using the synthetic event after it's expired.

Comment: See the code in my answer for an example of how to do it without a callback - instead of doing `setState(oldState => newState)` do `setState(newState)`. No, the current code does not look correct, since it's re-using the event after it's expired.

Comment: Just remove the callback, and pass the plain object to be set to the new state instead - as is done in the answer. Remove the `=>` and what comes before it in the state setter. This part is super simple, I promise.

Comment: The code is already present in my answer: `setformData({ ...formData, [name]: e.currentTarget.value })` You need to call the state setter with the new state value instead of passing it a callback.

Comment: `onChange={setformData({ ...formData, [name]: e.currentTarget.value }) }` gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`

Comment: You forgot to use the parameter. `onChange={e => {` etc - exactly like it is in the answer. If you use copy and paste to transfer code, you'll run into fewer issues with typos.

Comment: I tried `onChange={(e) => { setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: e.currentTarget.value }) }}` with `<Input placeholder="address to" name="addressTo" type="text"  {...{ formData, setFormData }} />` Nothing is inserted into field and get no errors. Notice I'm using react `17` and yours is `16`.

Comment: The code in the answer does not result in the problem you describe. Press "Run code snippet". Changing from 16 to 17 doesn't affect the functionality here.

Comment: Right, but unfortunatly your solution does not work for me. Appreciate your help nevertheless.

Comment: As always, you should include a [MCVE] in the question itself. If the code in your question doesn't result in the problem you're encountering (as is the case here) then you should work on constructing such a MCVE if you want others to be able to debug and fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

pass in a value on the input tag

```
<Input placeholder="address to" name="addressTo" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
```

to

```
<Input placeholder="address to" name="addressTo" value = {value} type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
```

Comment: This causes `@react-refresh:317 Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined`